# Class CKPPTSubTest is implemented in both frameworks. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imessage, imessage-extension

I am developing **Sticker Pack Application**. Under `Stickers.xcstickers`, I add some stickers and run the application on device. Except my stickers other installed stickers are working fine. When I select my sticker app, only logo is shown, no stickers are showing. I am getting one warning on console (everytime when i select my sticker ):-

> objc[491]: Class CKPPTSubTest is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit
>   (0x1af165ac0) and /Applications/MobileSMS.app/MobileSMS (0x1001461a8).
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

We are seeing this too on all our iMessage Extension related applications. I assume this is an Apple issue. You can safely ignore this log message, but you can not suppress it.

Comment: ok. I am also not able to see my stickers in the device. However they are showing in my simulator. Do I need to change any particular setting on xcode/device so that my stickers will show in the iMessage app.

Comment: They should show on a device as well, but you have to actively open a chat, select your sticker pack and wait (quite long, up to 40 seconds) until it gets loaded in my experiences.

Comment: I wait for more than 1 minute. I restart the iMessage app too. But the stickers don't load. Is there any way/app where i can test my stickers

Comment: Decribe the issue as detailed as possible, maybe in a separate question. We do the following: Build & Run for device -> iMessage obens on device. Select a chat. Click the arrow (->) button on the left of the textfield to show options. Click the App icon(A). Swipe through the extensions until you find yours. Your consoles text (in Xcode) shortly blinks, as the app is started. From this point, your stickers shold be shown within the next 60 seconds. If the console text does not flicker (happens sometimes), start the procedure again (build & run...).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply but it will help someone   try this hope work for you - in your device Settings < General < Device Management < select your Profile and "Trust" and Again run the app